# Migrated CVS to new server - why did the file commit with a weird, non-cvs, group name?

Tags: permissions, group, repository, cvs

We just migrated a cvs file repository from one server to another.

To test it out, I checked out, changed, then committed a file.

The owner / group changed from "cvs / cvs" to "MyAccount / SomeoneElseAccount".

I was expecting at least "MyAccount / cvs".

1. What was I supposed to expect?
2. Do I need to resolve this, or is this OK?
3. How might I resolve this if it is not OK?

UPDATE

Per the comments, I checked user ids.  Results on same line after '='.

```
id -u cvs = 60000
id -g cvs = 60000
id -G cvs = 600000 20 40

id -u MyAccount = 200007
id -g MyAccount = 200002
id -G MyAccount = 200002 60000 100005 100025

id -u SomeoneElseAccount = 200002
id -g SomeoneElseAccount = 200002
id -G SomeoneElseAccount = 200002 100678
```

I also had "AnotherUser" check out and commit; his file also ended up with group "SomeoneElseAccount".

```
id -u AnotherUser = 200018
id -g AnotherUser = 200002
id -G AnotherUser = 200002 60000 100005 100025
```

Setup on the old server provides a similar id configuration with 200002, though cvs is '100' there, and the items are committed as group 'cvs'.

Checking /etc/group

OLD SERVER

```
cat /etc/group
...
cvs:!:200002:name,name,name,MyAccount,AnotherUser,name,name...
...
```

NEW SERVER

```
cat /etc/group
...
cvs:!:60000:name,name,name,MyAccount,AnotherUser,name,name...
...
```

Comment: Are you using the `PreservePermissions` option or not?

Comment: Even if you preserved the permissions in your copy, did you make sure that the system user id (number) match up between the two machines?

Comment: PreservePermissions is set to no, as it was in the original system.  I am OK with that since it works fine.  PreservePermissions doesn't seem to have anything to do with changing the owner or group .  Also all the CVS guides say to not use it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier How do I check which system user id number CVS is using for creating files and correct it?

Comment: You look at that in the password file:  `/etc/passwd`.  3rd field is the user id and the 4th is their main group id.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I updated the question with a number of results from checking the id

Comment: We changed the group id of CVS on the new server to 200002, and that seems to work, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is apparent in your last update.

Lines...

> id -g MyAccount = 200002

and...

> id -g SomeoneElseAccount = 200002

.. should not have the same id.  As I pointed out in my comments, this is an error in your `/etc/passwd` file.

I would suggest that you also adjust the `/etc/group` file to match the old system.